# Probability brainteaser

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, card-games

Normal 52 card deck. Cards are dealt one-by-one. You get to say when to stop. After you say stop you win a dollar if the next card is red, lose a dollar if the next is black. Assuming you use the optimal stopping strategy, how much would you be willing to pay to play? Proof?

Answer (score 5):

The quick solution is: you may just bet on the color of the last card in the deck, not the next one. The game is not changed as you have the same info about next and last cards in the deck. So any strategy in original game is optimal :)

The teaser is mentioned in Peter Winkler's [Games people don't play](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=F55E6F6A731D0AFD04FC39F81BDF7C8A?doi=10.1.1.102.8855&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: I don't know why this has downvotes. The link to "Games people don't play" has a detailed solution, and Roah's solution translates it fairly (although perhaps with not enough detail).

Answer (score -1):

You should pay 0.5 because you can decide just before the last card is dealt. The probability that the last card is red is 1/2 and you will win 1; otherwise you don't say stop. Thus, the expectation of this game should be 0.5